# Understanding algorithm from Robert Sedgewick's Algorithms

Tags: c#, algorithm

Studding Robert Sedgewick's Algorithms I found his example not to clear for me.

Consider following algorithm:

```
    public static int count(int[] a, out int ifExecutions)
    {  // Count triples that sum to 0.
        ifExecutions = 0;
        int N = a.Length;
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
                for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++)
                {
                    ifExecutions ++;
                    if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0) //   N (N - 1)(N - 2) / 6 
                        cnt++;
                }
        return cnt;
    }
```

Robert Sedgewick in his book wrote:

> .... Others require higher-level reasoning: for  example, the if statement
>   in ThreeSum.count() is executed precisely  N (N - 1)(N - 2)/6 ....

I cannot figure out in what way number "6" here has appeared. Can someone explain?

Comment: Try mentally stepping the nested loops for some small values of N.

Comment: I guess that comes from N!/(N-3)!3!. 3! = 3.2.1 = 6

Comment: Note that it may be better asked on http://cs.stackexchange.com/ ... But since SO have detailed explanation already - dup here is ok too.